# jquery ui css not loading and creating problems with asp.net mvc3 page (unexpected token error)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-theme

First off, I can see that my mvc3 project already had jquery ui in it but no theme css files.

I needed a date picked and as usual needed to override the EditorFor DateTime. I started off today by just using the default jquery ui js files supplied with the project under scripts. The date picker shows up fine, only with a completed messed up UI based on Site.css.

So now I downloaded a build of jquery (with the **start** theme) and followed [this page](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/jquery_ui_mvc_intro.ashx) about how to put it together.

I'm using T4MVC so my page looks like this:
**Layout.cshtml**:

```
<script src="@Links.Scripts.jquery_1_4_4_js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Links.Content.Site_css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Links.Content.start.jquery_ui_1_8_7_custom_css" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
 <script src="@Links.Scripts.jquery_validate_min_js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Links.Scripts.jquery_validate_unobtrusive_min_js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Links.Scripts.jquery_ui_1_8_7_custom_min_js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And this is the result:
[image]

Any ideas, I tried a couple combinations of where I put the script and css files tags in different places, but nothing seems to work.

---

**Update**: So I was a dumbhead to have a `<script>` instead of a `<link>` tag in the layout! But there is still a problem, the date picker shows with the css from *Site.css*.
[image]

---

**Update 2: With Solution**

So I checked chrome and under resources I can't see the jquery css file. I fire fiddler and I don't see any request for the css file.

The I see it!

`<link href="@Links.Content.start.jquery_ui_1_8_7_custom_css" **rel="Stylesheet"** type="text/css" />`

Yes! Thats right, I didn't add a rel!

Comment: This is probably a javascript error.  Can you post your javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Layout.cshtml you are using a script tag to include the css file.
Change:

`<script src="@Links.Content.start.jquery_ui_1_8_7_custom_css" type="text/javascript"><script>` to

```
<link href="@Links.Content.start.jquery_ui_1_8_7_custom_css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

Comment: sweet lord! Guess this is what happens when your 3 days away from shipping a release (a preview release =P). Thanks.. but there is still a problem. Updating answer...

Comment: Can you post the html/css/js to jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Thanks so much cybernate!! I'm going to stop and watch a movie now!!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to put a wrapping container around the datepicker. It'll take two steps to do this:

1. When downloading the jquery ui file, click the "Advanced Theme Settings" and you'll a field for "CSS scope". This allows you to localize the css for the datepicker to a specific class/scope. For this example let's call it "jqueryui_element".
2. Once you hook up the new css file, you're going to have to wrap it with the css class/scope you defined. The easiest way I've found to do this is the following line of javascript:

   `$('#ui-datepicker-div').wrap('<div class="jqueryui_element"></div>');`

`#ui-datepicker-div` is the default id that gets applied to the datepicker elements. If for some reason you changed this it'll have to get updated here as well.

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 Very interesting. This might come in handy for me sometime later =)